# Upgrade to iOS 9 Final from Public Beta?

Tags: ios, upgrade, beta-seed-program, auto-update

I've been trying out iOS 9 Public Betas on my iPad and I'm pretty happy with it, but yesterday I got a prompt to update to v9.**1** beta... Which is probably a bit too *tender* for my tastes :-)

Anyhow I was wondering what'd be the process to move from the public beta to the final version when available?

Will removing the beta profile and rebooting mean I'll get the prompt to update to final when available next week? I think that's what make sense (I don't think Apple *really* expects all Public Beta users to restore from Backup)

Or do I have to wait until 9.0.1 as some answers in this site suggest? (These answers were mostly related to moving from GM to final; in that case the build # is likely the same so it *makes sense* that you don't get a prompt to update).

Really hoping that update doesn't entail wipe and restore

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As no answers are forthcoming, I'll report here my findings.

On 2015-09-16 , before iOS 9 GA, I removed the "Beta" profile from the iPad and rebooted. After reboot, `software update` says:

> iOS 9.0.
>   Software is up to date

The version of the software is `9.0 (13A4325c)`

So it looks good. There's an oddity, though. When I've rebooted (and hard-restart too to be on the safe side), every time I unlock the iPad I still get a notification saying:

> There's an update available. Update the iOS 9 beta version.

I **hope** that when 9.0 final comes up, the update check will pick it and I'll be back into mainline versions. I'll update here when things change.

**Edit 2015-09-16 19:39 CEST**: Apple has just released v9.0 final and going to software update in Settings I get prompted to upgrade, so it looks like I'll be able to get back to mainstream. The notification after login stills says the same. Will report later when I have the chance to upgrade.

**Edit 2015-09-18**: After installing the 9.0 update, and the subsequent reboot, the device says its updated to 9.0 and I no longer get the prompt to update -- so all seems to be fine!

**Edit 2015-09-25**: Just a final update to confirm that after a few days running, all seems to be fine. I've just got the prompt to update to 9.0.1, so I seem to be fully in "mainstream" now.

Answer (score 1):

I have the *exact* same issue as JJarava. I've been seeing a prompt to update to a new beta version (9.1), every time I unlock my phone, for a few days now...it's pretty annoying.

I, too, have 9.0 (13A4325c) installed. [That version](http://9to5mac.com/2015/08/06/ios-9-beta-5-iphone-ipad-ipod-touch/) *is* iOS 9 Beta 3. It would be nice if that version number indicated something about it being a beta version.

I digress. With iOS 9 Beta 3 installed, deleting the beta profile, restarting, and checking for software updates did *indeed* find iOS 9 GA for me.

If you upgrade to iOS 9.1 Beta, I suspect that you'll have to do a restore to *downgrade* back to 9.0.

Comment: I agree with you in all counts. V9.0 Public Beta 3 is exactly the same version than Developer Beta 5 IIRC, but they *could* tag it with "beta" (how likely is that any given beta will go "as is" to be final for that to be an issue!?) As for 9.1 Beta to 9.0 GA, as mentioned to @Dilsher, I think that counts as a "*downgrade*" so the path is likely restore and reinstall...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and here is how I solved it (both on my iPad and iPhone):

1. Connect your iDevice to a Mac or PC with iTunes installed.
2. Have iTunes running.
3. Shut down your device.
4. Remove the Thunderbolt USB cable, if connected.
5. Hold down the home button while you plugin the Thunderbolt USB cable. Hold down the home button until a "Connect to iTunes prompt appears". It's an image showing the iTunes logo and a USB cable.
6. For me, in iTunes a message appeared stating that there is a problem with my device and that I need to run an update. Just click the update button and iTunes will download and install the final version of iOS 9.