# How to install the final release of iOS 9 on an iPad running iOS 9 Beta

Tags: ios, beta-seed-program

Before someone closes this as a duplicate, my question is NOT the same as [this Ask Different post.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/205326/138476)

I've tried everything that the link above described, trying to install the final version of iOS 9 on my iPad that is currently running the iOS 9 Public Beta.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, as I've deleted the Beta profile in Settings, restarted my iPad again and again, but yet my only option is to install the iOS 9.1 Public Beta, which I don't want to do.

What can do to resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upgrade iOS 10 beta to iOS 10 final/public release](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/252503/upgrade-ios-10-beta-to-ios-10-final-public-release)

Comment: @GrahamMiln My question came out a year before that one. If anything, that question is a duplicate of mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this from the Apple support site:

"**Download the final version of iOS**

If you have an iOS beta version and want to download the final version, follow these steps:

Connect your device to iTunes.

While your device is connected, force it to restart. Press and hold the Sleep/Wake and Home buttons at the same time. Don't release when you see the Apple logo. Keep holding until you see the Recovery Mode screen.

When asked, choose Update to download and install the latest nonbeta version of iOS.

An update install won't affect your content or settings."

I would recommend backing your iOS device up to iTunes before attempting this.